# passing ID to click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have the following input inside an asp.net repeater

```
 <div class="detailsItem">
    <input type="button" class="saveCommand" value="Save"/>
 </div>
```

then within my document.ready I bind a click function

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.saveCommand').live('click', function () {
            var cur = $(this);
            saveItem(cur.closest('div.detailsItem'));
        });

    });
```

When I'm binding my repeater, i want to be able to include an ID in call to the `click` function. something similar to:

```
<input type="button" onclikc="save(this,<%#((CustomViewItem)Container.DataItem).Id%>" value="Save"/>
```

Any idea on how to combine the two styles of binding?

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You can add a `data` attribute for example. http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: It's better to use `.on()` than `.delegate()`, if you're using jQuery 1.7+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a [`data` attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

```
<!--
    <div class="detailsItem" data-id="<%#((CustomViewItem)Container.DataItem).Id%>">
-->
<div class="detailsItem" data-id="YourIdHere">
    <input type="button" class="saveCommand" value="Save"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.saveCommand').on('click', function () {
            var cur = $(this);
            var detailsItem = cur.closest('div.detailsItem');
            alert(detailsItem.data("id"));
            saveItem(detailsItem);
        });
    });
</script>
```

More information on the `data()` method in jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Data .

Comment: I guess I have used custom attributes to solve similar problems in the past. I guess this would be the *right* way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the new `data-*` attributes

```
<input type="button" data-id="<%#((CustomViewItem)Container.DataItem).Id%>" value="Save"/>
```

in the event handler you can then access it with

```
cur.data("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can pass the ID to the Save function in the Item Template of your Repeater.

```
<itemTemplate>
    <input type='button' onclick='save(<%# Eval("Id")); %>' value='Save' />
</itemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="detailsItem">
<input type="button" class="saveCommand" onclick='save(<%# Eval("Id") %>);' value="Save"/>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```